# How to show many pictures in ListView?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-image

I have an application - simple file manager, which show thumbnails for pictures and video using MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.getThumbnail() and MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(). But it working slow in directories where many pictures. How to fix it?

Part of code:

```
private ArrayList<File> filesList = new ArrayList<File>();

// ...

class FilesListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    // ...

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        File file = filesList.get(position); 

        Bitmap thumbnailBitmap = null;
        ContentResolver crThumb = getContentResolver();
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(mResource, parent, false);
        ImageView thumbnail = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);

        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            thumbnail.setImageResource(R.drawable.efp__ic_folder);
        } else {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 5) {
                try {
                    if (Arrays.asList(videoExtensions).contains(getFileExtension(file.getName()))) {
                        Cursor cursor = crThumb.query(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, new String[] { MediaStore.Video.Media._ID }, MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA + "='" + file.getAbsolutePath() + "'", null, null);
                        if (cursor != null) {
                            if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
                                cursor.moveToFirst();
                                thumbnailBitmap = MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(crThumb, cursor.getInt(0), MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND, null);
                            }
                            cursor.close();
                        }
                    } else if (Arrays.asList(imagesExtensions).contains(getFileExtension(file.getName()))) {
                        Cursor cursor = crThumb.query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, new String[] { MediaStore.Images.Media._ID }, MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA + "='" + file.getAbsolutePath() + "'", null, null);
                        if (cursor != null) {
                            if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
                                cursor.moveToFirst();
                                thumbnailBitmap = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(crThumb, cursor.getInt(0), MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND, null);
                            }
                            cursor.close();
                        }
                    }
                } catch(Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (Error e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if (thumbnailBitmap == null) thumbnail.setImageResource(R.drawable.efp__ic_file);
            else thumbnail.setImageBitmap(thumbnailBitmap);
        }

        // ...

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

Here is full code, if it needed: https://github.com/bartwell/ExFilePicker/blob/master/ExFilePicker/src/ru/bartwell/exfilepicker/ExFilePickerActivity.java

Comment: In general, calling external memory resource is an expensive operation, a possible optimization would be to transfer all the images from `filesList` as soon as you initialize it on a separate Thread to internal (operating) memory, and then load them in respective ImageViews. Then again, I don't know what kind of pictures they are, and this might not be good solution if they have large size.

Comment: @NitroNbg, Thank you for answer! It can have any images - from small to big. Please, look screenshotes here: https://github.com/bartwell/ExFilePicker/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should read http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html
and especially the part about loading the images off the UI Thread.

You can grab and adapt a lot of code from the provided sample project (BitmapFun).

(I had the same issue before and using this strategy help me a lot ;-) )

Answer (score 1):

I used to struggle with Image loading trought out all my applications.
Then [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) came out.

I strongly suggest you to use this library if your app uses lots of bitmap.
It will save you a ton of work